# Get user data using passport access token - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt, access-token

I've been trying to return user data using access token but keep getting error:

```
Invalid payload
```

My method was to get the token then find the user id from `oauth_access_tokens` table. My code is as follows:

```
public function authenticateUser($token){
     $user_id = DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')->where('id', trim($token))->value('user_id');
     $user = \App\User::find($user_id);

     Auth::login($user, true);
}
```

The token is something like this:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjkyZGU3ZGYyMDcxZjgzMzU5YWUxMmRlYzM4ZGJiM2EyMTk0NzEyYTQ5NmRiNzgwZWJkMDg2Yjc0NThkZjU0NmFlZmU2Yzg0N2Q0Mjc5MDAxIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiOTJkZTdkZjIwNzFmODMzNTlhZTEyZGVjMzhkYmIzYTIxOTQ3MTJhNDk2ZGI3ODBlYmQwODZiNzQ1OGRmNTQ2YWVmZTZjODQ3ZDQyNzkwMDEiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzczNzE4MDYsIm5iZiI6MTU3NzM3MTgwNiwiZXhwIjoxNjA4OTk0MjA1LCJzdWIiOiIzMCIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.Io4xkJYEczbI7rhFD_UKAoe7v_1-RLJXjA6XqGIe2nRAWEgMkg-mokQUiGz41xYVazmDmACDwwYSRr-iTTzwc591NABfxsmMk7OdYkUKb93UTA3JhKClEGSP82y1QrIfm9XTZ0KKDaCKlfKqye1Aobj9zFthQdApegTaK61ReLQa7MzO6EM5fcZ3udsLL3QpKXFuyO6JcPKRauKIbA8oNIKEdadprLWJSeQieIyA8lpYOr453QzgZGgzCwPY1U2RmIbCzqyNQD_L5264-ix1503KxgPt4F_Cl82WXm7tNsZKNwE-vGKhCc2CcgAgTV1lIj7ItDf2KpDh_Jt96Uiv2eJ3OtXYvuOTErz9mNnQ1T38hxQmKDh8XlG3f7JgIWWzN6m8ItBV1KyGZi0-vn2HXetkZTNIyfJV8E5-RaGUzIKX7RejWd5BVaqFw0OjDYPeliVOaZzfcZCRnPDSJBGwf7YqJrRXP61LMasn_ZJ-i8G5JIaQx2vdmfYgE41O5F9fE5uEF5-mIV979RbnswL6CJsSGmmUMzC7mPhqL6HtPu2hMTnfHbKY0-efqtzZ5I2TBQU6ODM37RFN5TEljoEgBFG6kAImkGDy4QFH5uqt6V7-ZFxvrKQzQozgezSgA6ITF1sRb7yWfI-9rF7sYE_aKu3r1_KRr4UJLoZqFyvGPP0
```

Isn't it the token that I should pass to the function above. When I pass it to `base64_decode`, I see the JSON object along with other gibberish. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reached to way to do so eventually by sending a request to the api in the other machine while adding the token in the header:

```
public function authenticateUser($token) {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        try {
            $response = $client->request('GET', env('APP_API_URL') . '/api/v2/user_data', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
                ],
            ]);

            $request = (string) $response->getBody();
            $request = json_decode($request);
            $user = User::where('email', $request->data->user->email)->first();
            Auth::login($user, true);
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            dd('Something went wrong while connection to the api');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Laravel Passport before, but I would imagine that the user is already authenticated when using the token. So maybe a route like:

```
Route::get('/user', function(Request $request) {
    return Auth::user();
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

Comment: I am using post request to send the token from another app to this current app. and then I authenticate the user in this app.

Comment: Oh okay. So are we talking about an implicit grant token? Or a different kind?

Comment: @MEDZ you know you need the same app key (in both apps) to decrypt any encrypted stuff?